# Can not build GTK+ Windows application on Fedora Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, mingw, cross-compiling

I try to build a very simple application for Windows x86 on Fedora x64 Eclipse with MinGW.
Application compiles good, however, it can not link. My link command follows:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ `mingw32-pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` -o "GtkTest"  ./main.o
```

When I run mingw32-pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0, the output follows:

```
-Wl,-luuid -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpango-1.0 -lm -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

In no doubts folder and library files exist. However, I receive following errors:

```
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3e): undefined reference to `gtk_init_abi_check'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x43): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_new'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3d): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_add_from_file'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x46): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_get_type'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x58): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_get_object'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x64): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x76): undefined reference to `gtk_builder_connect_signals'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x86): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8e): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x96): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9b): undefined reference to `gtk_main'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xcb): undefined reference to `g_log'
./main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd7): undefined reference to `g_free'
```

So, it looks like linker doesn't see libraries at all, even they exist and I reference them in command line.
What may be the reason?

Comment: Try moving object file before `pkg-config` i.e. `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ./main.o \`mingw32-pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0\` -o "GtkTest"`, see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are missing the `--cflags` but, above all,</s> The order [is wrong](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l-1042). Check out [Tor Lillqvist's suggestion](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2010-February/msg00035.html) for proper flags ordering.

Comment: Hi, why do I need --cflags for linker? I thought --cflags is for compiler (compiler flags).